# Is this function symmetrical?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, functional-analysis, derivatives

I have created a function $B_{n,k}(f'(x),f''(x),\cdots,f^{(n-k+1)}(x))_{(f \rightarrow g)^c}$ that behaves as follows:

$$
B_{n,k}(f'(x),f''(x),\cdots,f^{(n-k+1)}(x))_{(f \rightarrow g)^c} = \frac{(a^{(k-c)\diamond} \diamond b^{c\diamond})_n}{(k-c)!c!}
$$

In order to understand this notation please refer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Convolution_identity)

I am questioning whether

$$
B_{n,k}(f'(x),f''(x),\cdots,f^{(n-k+1}(x))_{(f \rightarrow g)^c} = B_{n,k}(g'(x),g''(x),\cdots,g^{n-k+1}(x))_{(g \rightarrow f)^{n-c}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is, due to the definition:

$$
B_{n,k}(f'(x),f''(x),\cdots,f^{(n-k+1)}(x))_{(f \rightarrow g)^c} = \frac{(a^{(k-c)\diamond} \diamond b^{c\diamond})_n}{(k-c)!c!}
$$

When we switch the $c = k-c$ and swap the sets, we will get the same original function.
$$
B_{n,k}(f'(x),f''(x),\cdots,f^{(n-k+1)}(x))_{(f \rightarrow g)^c} = \frac{(b^{(k-(k-c))\diamond} \diamond a^{(k-c)\diamond})_n}{(k-c)!c!}
$$